# Is there any way to return the id of that last inserted record other than dslContext.lastID() in JOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq

I need to retrieve the ID of the last inserted record, so I can insert a value like 'ABCD-lastId' into a field for unique identification, in addition to the primary key. Are there any alternative methods for achieving this?

Currently I'm using last ID method of DSL Context for getting the id. But I'm not sure it is a good approach since at the same time some other record are inserted.

I'm using like this

```
dslContext.insertInto(table(name), field("email"), field("password"))
                .values("test@mail.com", "password")
                .execute();
        System.out.println(dslContext.lastID());
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What's the `CREATE TABLE` definition of the table you're inserting to?

Comment: I'm using POSTGRESQL. Create table definition is

    dslContext.createTable(name(tableName))
                .column("id", dataType.nullable(false).identity(true))
                .column("GUID", SQLDataType.VARCHAR.nullable(true))
                .columns(cols)
                .execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to return generated IDs with jOOQ in PostgreSQL:

Just add a [`RETURNING` clause to your `INSERT` statement](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-returning/). For PostgreSQL, this is supported natively by jOOQ:

```java
Record result =
dslContext.insertInto(table(name), field("email"), field("password"))
                .values("test@mail.com", "password")
                .returningResult(field("guid"))
                .fetchOne();
System.out.println(result);
```

#### A note on using the code generator:

It's generally recommended to use [jOOQ's code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) for almost all cases (except when you have a dynamic schema). You'll get compile time type safety and a lot of other great benefits, among others, you can use [jOOQ's `UpdatableRecord` for simplified CRUD](https://tjooq). The `UpdatableRecord`, by default, fetches generated keys for you, automatically:

```java
MyTableRecord r = ctx.newRecord(MY_TABLE);
r.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
r.setPassword("password");
r.store();
System.out.println(r.getGuid()); // this has been fetched automatically
```

#### Schema mapping for multi tenancy

You're using `table(name)`, which hints at a dynamic schema, but do note that if the only reason your schema is dynamic is multi tenancy, then please note that jOOQ has a solution for that called [catalog, schema, and table mapping](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/)